# IE8 / IE9 Toolbar Cookies Check

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies, toolbar

How do i check for domain cookies in IE8/IE9 programatically using a C# built toolbar?

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in on my site using a site specific toolbar

When the user logs in on the website, a cookie is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [InternetGetCookie()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Or perhaps `InternetGetCookieEx()`.